# Is the Hive Rand() function inclusive or exclusive of 0 and 1?

Tags: random, hive

The docs for the [Apache Hive Rand() function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-MathematicalFunctions) say

> Returns a random number (that changes from row to row) that is distributed uniformly from 0 to 1. Specifying the seed will make sure the generated random number sequence is deterministic.

Can anyone tell me if this is inclusive or exclusive of the endpoints 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive's `rand` function is [currently implemented](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFRand.java) using [`java.util.Random#nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble--), which is documented to be a random `double` "chosen (approximately) uniformly from the range 0.0d (inclusive) to 1.0d (exclusive)", that is, in the interval [0, 1).

However, as you note, the formulation "from 0 to 1" can be ambiguous, at least more so than interval notation or the use of the words *inclusive* or *exclusive*, and it's at least possible that the implementation of `rand` could, say, change to one that generates numbers in the closed interval [0, 1], which is arguably consistent with the formulation "from 0 to 1".  If this is something you care about, file an issue on [Apache JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HIVE).